# appending to a dictionary with a list

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary in the following format:

```
{'Dickens,Charles': [['Hard Times', '7', '27.00']],
 'Shakespeare,William': [['Rome And Juliet', '5', '5.99'],
                     ['Macbeth', '3', '7.99']]}
```

I want to append to this dictionary by asking the user for the author's last and first name, which is the key, then book name, quantity, then price. If the author already exists, it should create another list of lists.

```
def displayInventory(theInventory):
    for names, books in sorted(theInventory.items()):
        for title, qty, price in sorted(books):
            print("Author: {0}".format("".join(names)))
            print("Title: {0}".format(title))
            print("Qty: {0}".format(qty))
            print("Price: {0}".format(price))
            print()


def addBook(theInventory):
    my_list = []
    hello = True
    flag = True
    first = input("Enter the first name of the author: ")
    last = input("Enter the last name of the author: ")
    last = last[0].upper() + last[1:].lower()
    first = first[0].upper() + first[1:].lower()
    author = last + "," + first
    book = input("Enter the title of the book: ")
    book = book.lower()
    book = book.title()
    j = 0

 if author not in theInventory:
    while flag:
        try:
            qty = int(input("Enter the qty: "))
            price = input("Enter the price: ")
            my_list.append(str(book))
            my_list.append(str(qty))
            my_list.append(str(price))
            theInventory[author] = my_list
            flag = False
        except ValueError:
            ("no")

 else:
      for i in theInventory[author][j]:
      if theInventory[author][j][0] == book:
          print("The title is already in the Inventory")
          hello = False

          while flag:
              qty = int(input("Enter the qty: "))
              if qty > 0:
                  flag = False
                  tree = True
                    while tree:
                        price = input("Enter the price: ")
                        my_list.append(str(book))
                        my_list.append(str(qty))
                        my_list.append(str(price))
                        theInventory[author].append(my_list)
                        j+=1
                        tree = False
```

This keeps throwing errors when I try to print theInventory from main after updating it.

```
File "practice.py", line 270, in <module>
main()
File "practice.py", line 254, in main
 displayInventory(theInventory)
File "practice.py", line 60, in displayInventory
for title, qty, price in sorted(books):
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

It doesn't update the dictionary at all if its an author that did exist previously, and after adding a new author with the values it throws the error.

Comment: What error it keeps throwing?

Comment: @user3599753 learn one think about error traces - use them. Start by reading them, it contains answer to what is the problem. And if you do not manage understanding it and come to Stack Overflow, do show us the error traces without being asked over and over.

Comment: also please format your code. indentation is somewhat important in python

Comment: where is the value for  author coming from?

Comment: No, I have other functions where I update the price and such, and they work fine. Its just adding an entire book that is the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last three lines of the traceback is very helpful:

```
File "practice.py", line 60, in displayInventory
for title, qty, price in sorted(books):
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

The error message indicates that `books` does not contain what you think it does (a list of lists).  The traceback shows the error occurring here:

```
for title, qty, price in sorted(books): # <= ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
    print("Author: {0}".format("".join(names)))
    ... # the rest of the loop
```

Wrap this loop in a try/except to see what `books` really contains.

```
try:
    for title, qty, price in sorted(books):
        print("Author: {0}".format("".join(names)))
        ... # the rest of the loop

except ValueError:
    print(books)
    raise
```

**Edit:**

The root cause of the error is here:

```
theInventory[author] = my_list
```

Since `theInventory` is supposed to contain a list of lists, change the assignment to

```
theInventory[author] = [my_list]
```